# Использование Google Guava

Tags: java, swing, gui

Пытаюсь разобраться с EventBus из библиотеки Google Guava. Хотелось бы посмотреть пример его использования относительно моей задачи. Другими словами, не могли вы показать пример использования ?

Допустим у меня есть некий класс, в котором есть вот такой вот внутренний класс-слушатель:

```
    private class StopScanButtonListener implements ActionListener {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        try {
            portConnection.writeByte((byte) 0xFF);
            portConnection.writeByte((byte) 0x05);
            portConnection.writeByte((byte) 0xFF);
        } catch (SerialPortException | NullPointerException e1) {
            labelState.setText("Ошибка! Возможно вы не подключились к устройству!");
            labelState.repaint();
        }
    }
}
```

Как я могу его вынести на шину?

P.S. Было бы еще лучше, если бы вы показали пример применения относительного [этого класса](https://github.com/Faoxis/KatinDipsach/blob/master/GUI/src/main/java/com/faoxis/gui/MainWindow.java). Но за пример относительно класса выше тоже буду очень признателен.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для начала, нужно создать класс описывающий событие:

```
public class TestEvent {

    private final String message;

    public TestEvent(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }
}
```

и обработчик события, ключевой тут является аннотация `@Subscribe`, при помощи нее шина и понимает, какое же событие мы собираемся слушать:

```
public class EventListener {
    @Subscribe
    public void listen(TestEvent event) {
        System.out.println(event.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Затем нужно где-то в приложении инициализировать экземпляр EventBus, например как общедоступное статическое поле в вашем главном классе:

```
public static final EventBus bus = new EventBus();
```

После чего зарегистрировать слушатель(слушатели) на шине:

```
bus.register(new EventListener());
```

Теперь, где бы ты ни было(у вас - внутри ActionListener для JButton) при вызове:

```
bus.post(new TestEvent("message"));
```

все слушатели этого типа события, получат его

Comment: Да, но ведь так слушателю будут недоступны поля и методы класса из которого он вызван, разве нет ?

Comment: необходимые данные нужно передавать через само событие, там я специально указал поле message

Comment: Понятно, спасибо! У меня вот только небольшая проблема. Создал я объект bus как вы написали выше, но метода register в нем найти не удается. Компилятор ругается на строку bus.register(new EventListener());

Comment: какую версию gauva вы подключили?

Comment: 19.0 через Maven

Comment: http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.google.guava/guava/19.0-rc1/com/google/common/eventbus/EventBus.java?av=f#187

Comment: напишите тогда ка ругается, т.к. метод такой, как вы можете наблюдать - имеется

Comment: Все метод появился. Просто я поторопился и начал его использовать еще когда Maven не все докачал. Не понятно только, что писать в метод addActionListener() и как bus с ним связан ?

Comment: По хорошему здесь еще надо вплетать dependency injection, но можно просто сделать его публичным статическим полем вашего главного класса

Comment: А что это такое ?

Comment: Если вы про DI , то это шаблон такой, вот например я использую это https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Guice

Comment: Все равно до конца не все понятно как это работает... Но за помощь огромное спасибо!